# Is it possible to drag a layer in OpenLayers?

Tags: html-lists, openlayers

Is it possible to drag an entire layer in openlayers? (similar to the way you drag a feature)

Comment: Yes, if you programmatically select all the features https://codesandbox.io/s/translate-features-forked-2dtwt

Comment: i didn't mean to drag all of the feature in a layer, i meant dragging the layer itself, and by that changing its' extent. @Mike

Comment: The extent of a layer determines the extent which is visible, changing it would not move anything inside that extent.

Comment: do you have a suggestion on how to move the layer's location? @Mike

Comment: @Mike any suggestions?

Comment: @Leonard Punt i saw youve encountered the same issue several years ago, how did you manage to fix it?